# How do I supply credentials to execute a query on a server that's part of another domain?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

I am doing work for a client that has a server on his domain.  My workstation is on my own domain.  I typically VPN into the client network using my client domain username and password.  The problem with the below query is that I get a 401 Unauthorized access error when I execute the query, presumably because the wrong credentials are being sent.

The client has suggested supplying my client domain credentials, perhaps wrapped in a #if DEBUG so that the code will work properly in development environments.

How do I supply credentials?  The following code will be present in an ASP MVC 2 project.

```
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(URL);
        List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("My Documents");

        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = XML;
        ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(
             listItems,
             items => items.Include(item => item["FileRef"]));

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I prefer to do this programatically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this all I need to do:

```
        System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myname", "mypassword"); 
    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(URL);

    clientContext.Credentials = cred;
```

I am still not getting success, but perhaps there are some other issues here.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the domain, e.g. new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myname", "mypassword", "domain")?

Comment: it turns out that the above code resolves the issue.  Resolving some other issues fixes my own unique flavor of this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure the Application Pool credential on the IIS, this way the "user" running the application has permission to access the other server.

Answer (score 0):

If the client account is already a valid user of the sharepoint site you just need to use the default credentials before downloading, like so..

```
WebClient Client=new WebClient();
Client.UseDefaultCredentials=true;
Client.DownloadFile(url, destination);
```