# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized in context.ExecuteQuery() : ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm using following code snippet to connect sharepoint server API. This snippet works well in blank project as expected. It returns the lists Announcements, Shared Documents, Tasks...etc.

But when I integrate this with existing application, it throws `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized` error message in `context.ExecuteQuery()`.

I tried providing `Context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( username, password, domain );` which returns the same error.

**Code:**

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(ServerUrl))
{
    //get all the lists from sharepoint
    //all the files and folders resides inside some list.
    Web web = context.Web;
    context.Load(web.Lists, its => its.Include(it => it.Title, it => it.Id, it => it.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl));

    context.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (var list in web.Lists)
    {
        //add all the lists to treeview
        //list id is assigned to node value and list's server relative url is assigned to tooltip
        tvItems.Nodes.Add(new Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNode
        {
            Value = list.Id.ToString(),
            Text = list.Title,
            ExpandMode = Telerik.Web.UI.TreeNodeExpandMode.ServerSide,
            ToolTip = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
        });
    }
}
```

I tried changing `context.Load(web.Lists, its => its.Include(...);` line of code to `context.Load(web.Lists, its => ClientObjectQueryableExtension.Include(...));` to make sure sharepoint reference not get mixed with existing once.

Any help would be great to solve the issue.

Comment: Since its a web process, you need to supply the credential details explicitly, check the following link and try:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708084/how-do-i-supply-credentials-to-execute-a-query-on-a-server-thats-part-of-anothe

Answer (score 0):

If you are tying to access context from within provider-hosted app you can use something like:

```
        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
        using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        { 
          .... 
        }
```